ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt, root filesystem requires a manual fsck (comment)
Comment on answer 1 above:
After "sudo mkdir /mnt" add "sudo mkdir /var/tmp", to avoid error "unable to allocate pty: no such device"

Can you please elaborate on the error and your question? Thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be a question, but rather a comment on an (unidentified) "answer 1 above"
